# Automate assignment of managed package licenses?

Tags: managed-package, licenses

We have a managed package that requires a license. We've purchased enough licenses for our entire company (2,500+ users). Assuming I know the SELECT statement that will get me a list of all these users, is there a way I can grant this license to all of these users via either Anonymous Apex or through the Data Loader? Additionally, how can I ensure that all new users who meet this same criteria are granted this license automatically going forward?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no API exposed to make writing a tool to do this possible. An idea has been raised for this very use case.

**Expose API / Objects for assigning Managed Package Licenses to Users**

> Currently the only way to assign a Seat License of an installed Managed Package to a particular user is through the Setup user interface --- there is no API or object which would allow a customer to programmatically assign licenses of an installed Managed Package to particular users.

Read more [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kvq4AAA).

**Where there is a will there is a way...**

Well in the spirit of never say never... there is the option of scripting the user interface using something like [WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) (from the **Selenium**) world. In theory something like this could be developed to work its way through users that meet certain criteria.

Answer (score 4):

I actually just solved my own problem. Well, at least the problem of getting existing users licensed. There is an "Add All Users" button, which at first glance I assumed would simply add the users that were currently visible, but after some fiddling I realized it will add all the users in whichever view you have selected, regardless of whether they are on the screen or not. So I created a view that contained the users to whom I wanted to grant licenses, then clicked the button. Voila! 2,500+ licenses quickly and painlessly assigned.

[image]

I still have the task of assigning the licenses to new users, but there is already a certain amount of manual process we go through for all new employees, so, in the absence of any way to script this in a workflow or trigger, we'll just have to add that to the rest of our manual new hire standard operating procedure.

Answer (score 0):

PermissionSetAssigment object supports create() call, so build a permissions set with your requirments and get all user ID's which need to have that particluar permission set.

select Id, PermissionSetId, AssigneeId, SystemModstamp from PermissionSetAssignment.

If it gives an error:CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, then we cannot do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

In Summer 14 access to UserPackageLicense object given to system administrators, this can be done through this object.

Answer (score 0):

There was an idea on SF community which was delivered in Summer 14 release:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kvq4AAA

Answer (score 0):

Check this article from Automation Champion, there is a much better way to handle auto assignment of package license to a user based on business conditions.

https://automationchampion.com/2022/03/17/auto-assign-package-license-to-new-users/